# Format table using column with columns containing spaced text

Tags: bash, shell

I have a below table

```
1  Data  2021-02-04
2  Data Two  2021-02-05
```

If I `column -t -s ''` I get

```
1  Data  2021-02-04
2  Data Two  2021-02-05
```

Any way I can format this as:

```
1  Data      2021-02-04
2  Data Two  2021-02-05
```

Or format by column number 3

Comment: What separates the columns? Tabs?

Comment: Double spaces between columns. Single space between the text in same column.

Comment: But your original table only has one space between `Data Two` and the date?

Comment: Let me re-edit, looks like funky ctrl+v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first convert the two spaces separating columns in the original into a single character before feeding it to `column`. Something like:

```sh
$ sed 's/  /|/g' input.txt | column -t -s '|'  
1  Data      2021-02-04
2  Data Two  2021-02-05
```

Use a different character that doesn't appear in the input if `|` is present in it.